# set query by using parameter after using with and inside case

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to make a query of all exists database, not very sure about the syntax but i get

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 24
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'set'.

any ideas?

```
declare @query varchar(max);
set @query = '';

with getAllAccount as(
select B.ID,B.DisplayName from (
select ID,DisplayName from u3_system.[dbo].[Account] with (nolock)
where ID = '8c76ef27-3080-4daa-881b-08cd2a1a558f' or ParentID = '8c76ef27-3080-4daa-881b-08cd2a1a558f') A
join u3_system.[dbo].[Account] B with (nolock)
on A.ID = B.ParentID
union 
select ID,DisplayName from u3_system.[dbo].[Account] with (nolock)
where ID = '8c76ef27-3080-4daa-881b-08cd2a1a558f'
),

getAllSurveys as(
 select s.ID,getAllAccount.DisplayName AccountName, s.DisplayName SurveyName,s.Status,s.LastModified from u3_survey.dbo.survey s with(nolock)
 inner join getAllAccount
 on S.AccountID = getAllAccount.ID
)

--select * from getAllSurveys
--order by LastModified desc
set @query += case when exists (select * from sys.tables where name = 'LiveResponse_' + replace(getAllAccount.ID,'-',''))
        Then 'Select ID,SurveyID from  u3_data.data.LiveResponse_' + replace(getAllAccount.ID,'-','') + ' with(nolock) union ' End 
    from getAllAccount
select @query
```

Comment: I've tagged this question with sql-server based on the syntax and the wording of the error message. In your future questions, please be sure to use all relevant tags. SQL Is just a language, and every rdbms has it's own tweaks to it.

Comment: Use SELECT instead SET command in line 24.

Comment: that doesnt work, it just says command complete sucessfully but nothing happened i tried before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select ' ' + execQuery from 
        (select * from 
            (select case when exists (select * from sys.tables where name = 'LiveResponse_' + replace(getAllAccount.ID,'-',''))
                Then 'Select SurveyID,Max(CompleteDate) CompleteDate from  u3_data.data.LiveResponse_' + replace(getAllAccount.ID,'-','') + ' with(nolock) group by SurveyID union ' End execQuery
            from getAllAccount
            ) A
        where execQuery is not null ) B
    For xml path ('')
```

then exec the query

Answer (score 0):

Please note that this sql statement reveals a meaningful flaw in your database design - You have multiple tables storing the same type of entities - the `u3_data.data.LiveResponse_XXX` tables.
This poor design is what got you in the current problem and is guaranteed to cause more problems in the future.

I highly recommend changing this design - and you'ld be surprised how simple it is: All you need to do is have a single table `u3_data.data.LiveResponse`, and add a column to store the `AccountID`.

This has several benefits compared to your current database design:

- First and formost - you can add a foreign key constraint between the `LiveResponse` table to the `Account` table, thus ensuring referential integrity.
  Even if this was the only benefit, it would still be a good enough reason to change the database design.
- Second - you will not have to mess around building dynamic SQL statements to interact with the `LiveResponse` table - Making your life as a developer much easier, your code much cleaner and the potential for dangers such as SQL Injection attacks much smaller.
  Again, this alone is a good enough reason to change the database design.
- Third - having all the data of a single entity spread over multiple table can cause huge performance issues. Keeping it in a single table might cause that table to grow, but professional databases can handle tables with many millions of rows. I personally am working with a database where some of it's tables have well over 100 million rows, and this is not considered a huge database in SQL Server terms.

All that being said, In case you can't change the database structure (and since you have such good reasons to change it, this should be in case you really can't), To directly answer your question, you need to use `select` instead of `set` as Jacek wrote in his comment.

Comment: We can't change the design i know its poor but we got more than thousand of clients using it. its the backend's decision thanks

Comment: Well, I would say that's a really good reason to change the structure. Of course, you can't do it directly on the production database, you have to create a copy of it and do it on the copy, and only once you're sure the re-design is working properly and no data gets lost in the process, do it on the production server.

Comment: I have talked to them, its because im join all the account and its subaccount of it, i think its not a bad thing to do it? the reason we have to split its because we got too much data for each table and etc of coz its much more then 100 millions rows. any other good idea to improve the database structure? thanks

Comment: I'm not a DBA but there are solutions I can think of like partitioning and filtered indexes. With this amount of data I would expect a DBA working with you. If your company doesn't employ one, there are consultants DBAs you can hire on  a time base (1 hour, 2 days, 3 weeks) that I'm sure can help you analyze your needs and come up with a solid database design much better than a stranger on the internet that don't know the first thing about your business.